# using SmtpClient and IDisposable

Tags: .net, idisposable, smtpclient

I've noticed that the majority of the example code using .NET's SmtpClient class don't Dispose the created object or wrap it in an using block. (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) Is the SmtpClient's dispose optional or not very important or are the examples leading us down the wrong path? Note: In the MSDN example provided above the MailMessage is disposed but not the SmtpClient object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that a lot of examples online don't show proper disposing code is that [SmtpClient didn't implement IDisposable until .NET 4](http://leedumond.com/blog/new-in-net-4-dont-forget-to-dispose-your-smtpclient-instances/). So the examples could be based on a previous framework, or written by someone unfamiliar with the new functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You have to dispose it.

In the example they use SendAsync(), that's why they do not use "using" keyword - SendAsync() returns immediately and you potentially can try to dispose an object which is currently in use. However, it is better to dispose the client when all async methods are done.

Comment: I realy have to learn to typ faster :P Exaclty, if you have a look at the documentation of "Dispose()" you will see that it will chancel the request if its called to early. (Maybe) They missed a "sender.Dispose()" in the end of the async handler. But I think  the Garbagecollector will be able to handle this.

Comment: Of cource GC will handle this, but the reason to implement IDisposable is to make possible to dispose objects on the early stage, before garbage collecting, in order to free some OS or external resources.

Answer (score 0):

Msdn examples omit things like that because the point is to demonstrate a concept clearly in a small focused article, not to write a correct robust production application.

Comment: If you poke around it's not only MSDN examples. I also think that's a bad concept, since many (most?) will follow the examples verbatim.